# web app chrome, javascript, adding functions to child window to access them from parent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, createwindow

I have the function to create a window

```
var new_panel;
chrome.app.window.create('empty.html', 
{
  id: 'protein_panel',
  outerBounds: {
    width: 300,
    height: 800,
    left: 1220,
    top: 100,
  },
  frame: 'none',
  resizable: false,
},
function(createdWindow) {
  createdWindow.contentWindow.close = function() {
    console.log('ei')
    createdWindow.close();
  }
new_panel = createdWindow;
}
);
```

And then, when I call the function triggered from the parent window (by a button)

```
new_panel.close();
```

What I get is infinite 'ei' in the console.log (and no "close" event)

Why is that happening?

UPDATE:
I have change the word 'close' since it could certainly interfere, so instead of 'close' I've put 'closing'

```
function(createdWindow) {
  createdWindow.contentWindow.closing = function() {
    console.log('ei')
    createdWindow.close();
  }
```

and

```
new_panel.closing();
```

and I get *Uncaught TypeError: new_panel.closing is not a function*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
I lacked the contentWindow

```
new_panel.contentWindow.closing();
```

*I have decided to post it anyway since I'd have appreciated a lot to have seen this question one hour ago